# Unity - cannot click UI button

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

The project is relatively new, and funnily enough, I have the **exact** same buttons (canvases too), and the one on level one works just fine, while the exact same button on level 2 does not work, I am not getting any errors either. I've looked at other threads, but couldn't find anything about this.

Pic 1: Level 2 Hierarchy
[image: egfgg]

pic 2: Level 2 Button Inspector[image]

pic 3: Level 1 Button Inspector (same one ^)[image]

Comment: Are you able to interact with it, i.e. hover, and are you able to use it to block other UI's raycasting?

Comment: hmm yeah, the highlighted color doesn't appear when I hover over it.

Comment: So am I correct to say that its not the button's `OnClick()` function that's not working, but rather, its entire `Button` component?

Comment: is it possible that there is any collider in between blocking the raycast?

Comment: yup, I fixed it, thanks

Comment: @mxm how did you fix it? If you are going to post on SO and state your issue is fixed then you should either mark an answer correct or provide your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Duplicating Buttons, OnClick problem:**
If you duplicated your button and transferred it to level 2, then your OnClick GameManager object points to the GameManager of level 1.

**Duplicating Scene:**
If you duplicated level 1 and renamed it to level 2, everything should work fine unless there are some singleton related code in your GameManager.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and had similar result.
you need to copy EventSystem from level 1.
reference : https://forum.unity.com/threads/ui-button-not-working-as-prefab.338262/
or just make a new canvas and place the button inside new canvas.

Comment: but at least in the screenshot there is already an EventSystem in Level2